# Obtain the same result as a for..in loop, without any for..in loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

(Let us suppose that there is a good reason for wishing this. See the end of the question if you want to read the good reason.)

I would like to obtain the same result as a `for in` loop, but *without* using that language construct. By result I mean only an array of the property names (I don't need to reproduce the behavior that would happen if I modify the object while iterating over it).

To put the question into code, I'd like to implement this function without `for in`:

```
function getPropertiesOf(obj) {
  var props = [];
  for (var prop in obj)
    props.push(prop);
  return props;
}
```

From my understanding of the ECMAScript 5.1 specification about [the for in statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) and [the `Object.keys` method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14), it seems the following implementation should be correct:

```
function getPropertiesOf(obj) {
  var props = [];
  var alreadySeen = {};

  // Handle primitive types
  if (obj === null || obj === undefined)
    return props;
  obj = Object(obj);

  // For each object in the prototype chain:
  while (obj !== null) {
    // Add own enumerable properties that have not been seen yet
    var enumProps = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < enumProps.length; i++) {
      var prop = enumProps[i];
      if (!alreadySeen[prop])
        props.push(prop);
    }

    // Add all own properties (including non-enumerable ones)
    // in the alreadySeen set.
    var allProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < allProps.length; i++)
      alreadySeen[allProps[i]] = true;

    // Continue with the object's prototype
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }

  return props;
}
```

The idea is to walk explicitly the prototype chain, and use `Object.keys` to get the own properties in each object of the chain. We exclude property names already seen in previous objects in the chain, including when they were seen as non-enumerable. This method should even respect [the additional guarantee mentioned on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, **in the same order as that provided by a
>   `for...in` loop** [...].

(emphasis is mine)

I played a bit with this implementation, and I haven't been able to break it.

**So the question:**

Is my analysis correct? Or am I overlooking a detail of the spec that would make this implementation incorrect?

Do you know another way to do this, that would match the implementation's specific order of `for in` in all cases?

Remarks:

- I don't care about ECMAScript < 5.1.
- I don't care about performance (it can be disastrous).

---

Edit: to satisfy @lexicore's curiosity (but not really part of the question), the good reason is the following. I develop a compiler to JavaScript (from Scala), and the `for in` language construct is not part of the things I want to support directly in the intermediate representation of my compiler. Instead, I have a "built-in" function `getPropertiesOf` which is basically what I show as first example. I'm trying to get rid of as many builtins as possible by replacing them by "user-space" implementations (written in Scala). For performance, I still have an optimizer that sometimes "intrinsifies" some methods, and in this case it would intrinsify `getPropertiesOf` with the efficient first implementation. But to make the intermediate representation sound, and work when the optimizer is disabled, I need a true implementation of the feature, no matter the performance cost, as long as it's correct. And in this case I cannot use `for in`, since my IR cannot represent that construct (but I can call arbitrary JavaScript functions on any objects, e.g., `Object.keys`).

Comment: `(obj === null || obj === undefined)` is the same as `obj == null`. Out of curiosity, is there a reason you are using the more verbose form?

Comment: @gilly3 Because `==` is evil. For a less opinionated answer: for the same reason that I can't use `for in`: the IR intentionally does not support `==` (because it's evil ...).

Comment: Interesting. I feel like `==` is actually a *strength* of the language that should be used judiciously.

Comment: @gilly3 A strength of JS the *language* that humans write, possibly. But as the target of compiling Scala, it's useless. If it is made accessible from Scala.js, it will look very queer at best, dangerously incomprehensible at worst. Scala already has an `==` operator which says something else (more or less the same as `equals` in Java) and another operator `eq` which corresponds to `===`). Adding a 3rd equality operator that is not strictly necessary (unlike some way to access `for in`) would be very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the specification point of view, your analysis correct only under assumption that a particular implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the for-in statement:

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the
>   for-in statement, that same enumeration order must be used in step 5
>   of this algorithm.

See the last sentence [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14).

So if an implementation *does not* provide such specific order, then for-in and `Object.keys` may return different things. Well, in this case even two different for-ins may return different things.

Quite interesting, the whole story reduces to the question if two for-ins will give the same results if the object was not changed. Because, if it is not the case, then how could you test "the same" anyway?

In practice, this will most probably be true, but I could also easily imagine that an object could rebuild its internal structure dynamically, between for-in calls. For instance, if certain property is accessed very often, the implementation may restructure the hash table so that access to that property is more efficient. As far as I can see, the specification does not prohibit that. And it is also not-so-unreasonable.

So the answer to your question is: **no, there is no guarantee according to the specification, but still will probably work in practice**.

**Update**

I think there's another problem. Where is it defined, what the order of properties between the members of the prototype chain is? You may get the "own" properties in the right order, but are they merged exactly the way as you do it? For instance, why child properties first and parent's next?

Comment: Right, I understand that. But if the underlying implementation does *not* define a specific order, then my function also satisfies the spec, doesn't it? Since there's nothing to satisfy in terms of order, any order, including the precise one I use, is fine; the requirement is basically void.

Comment: @sjrd You are right, there is just no way to prove otherwise. Which requirement is void, exactly?

Comment: The requirement to return the names in the same order as what `for in` would do. If the underlying implementation does not guarantee any sort of order, then this requirement is void.

Comment: @sjrd Correct, this is how I would see it. But iff there's no guarantee. If there is one, then the requirement is sound and reasonable. But judging from how deep your understanding of the matter is, you already know that. :)

Comment: @sjrd Oh wait. I think there's another problem. Where is it defined, what the order of properties between the members of the prototype chain is? You may get the "own" properties in the right order, but are they merged exactly the way as you do it? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Yes, that might be a problem, indeed :-( I don't see how to fix this ... Maybe I'll just live with the difference, for that corner case.